# Pyinstaller Not Compiling Large Program in Python2.7 64-Bit Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, pyinstaller

I have been having some difficulties compiling my Python program using Pyinstaller. My program has multiple modules and about 2000 lines of code. It uses TaurusScada as a sort of wrapper for PYQT, Numpy, and a few other modules. The platform is Python 2.7 and Ubuntu 15.04. I'm also using Pyinstaller 3.1. I was successful in compiling a small "Hello World" type application so I know it works. I am not married to Pyinstaller as I have tried cx_Freeze as well without success. Rather than leaving my entire code on here I'll start by leaving the traceback and error in hopes that someone can shed some light on this:

```
    66874 INFO: Processing hook   hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 755, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 701, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 183, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 432, in assemble
    imphook_object = ImportHook(imported_name, hook_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/building/imphook.py", line 182, in __init__
    self._module = importlib_load_source(hook_modname, self._filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-gi.repository.GdkPixbuf.py", line 36, in <module>
    cachedata = subprocess.check_output('gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have not used PyInstaller for a few years, but I remember it often had trouble adding some more elaborate packages or modules and I had to add them manually to the .spec file. Have you tried using `--hiddenimport` flag for modules that are used in hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a similar error today. You are missing the gdk-pixbuf library:

so just run:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
```

and pyinstaller should go smoothly